# asyncio.Task cancel() does not cancel the task if it's not in event loop

Tags: python, async-await, task, python-asyncio

I've stumbled upon a rather counterintuitive behavior of Python. Version is 3.10.12, Ubuntu 22.04.

Consider this script:

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    t = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(5))
    t.cancel()
    print(t.cancelled())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print(t.cancelled())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

It writes:

```
False
True
```

Shouldn't it write

```
True
True
```

instead?

I assume the task first has to be committed to the event loop, before it can be cancelled. But isn't it really a bug? Shouldn't I be able to cancel the task regardless?

Comment: "cancelled(): Return True if the Task is cancelled. The Task is cancelled when the cancellation was requested with cancel() **and the wrapped coroutine propagated the CancelledError exception thrown into it.**" [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancelled)

Comment: @mkrieger1 i got you man, thanks